# How to use xip.io without IP address?

Tags: dns, wildcard, dyndns

How to use xip.io without IP address?

I see some sites from xip.io was created without IP address such any.xip.io.

However, I don't know how to set it and use it because I try to find a method but it has provide method to use xip.io with ip.address.xip.io only.

Thank you

Comment: http://any.xip.io/ does not exist.

Comment: @SLaks Thank you, because I found some of any.xip.io